# Get Facebook Photo lightbox

Tags: facebook, lightbox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have my own Canvas app and i want to get the original lightbox.

So you have the same case as in Facebook. Click on a Picture and get a lightbox for comments and so on.

I found a Thread about it here but there was no anser and it was old(Old Api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** use the Facebook theater mode (Facebook lightbox) in your apps. You need to use your own lightbox library keeping in mind that you are inside an iframe.

Comment: Yes, here's an [article](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-user-photo-albums-browser-using-facebook-graph-api/77/) that may help you (check the demo page) but please note that it's not in a canvas app.

Answer (score 0):

i designed a special facebook lightbox theme for the colorbox - you can use that, and it works with iframes.